# Отображение даты в SQLite Expert

Tags: sqlite3, дата

Спроектировал базу в SQLite Expert.
Само собой, что тип DATE отсутствует, но есть возможность использовать INTEGER (или другие варианты: real, text).
Так вот, я решил использовать INTEGER для хранения дат.
А как заставить SQLite Expert отображать и вводить данные именно в виде даты, а не цифры?

[image]

Comment: Лучше юзайте String. ИМХО. с интом могут траблы быть (сужу по MySQL там бывает такое

Comment: я думал об этом, но integer шустрее обрабатывается, ладно, главное чтобы в android-приложении нормально отображалось, посмотрим

Comment: @naym и какие же траблы бывают в MySQL с интом и почему это должно влиять на SQLite. Но в мускуле ведь есть поле нужного типа?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно дату хранить в виде string. Проблем целая кучка.

- сложно сортировать
- сложно сравнивать две даты.
- большой оверхед.
- любая минимальная арифметика с датами будет очень сложно.
- другие программы могут не работать корректно с Вашей базой.

Пусть даты хранятся в виде чисел. В виде строки они нужны только человеку. Если просто в sqlite expert захотелось посмотреть дату нормально, то вместо выводите так

```
select key, datetime(gen_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') from my_basa
```

вместо 'unixepoch' подставьте свою "базу для даты". Я просто привык использовать UnixTimeStamp. 'localtime' - заставит правильно преобразовать в нужный часовой пояс. Больше здесь [DateAndTimeFunctions](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions). Если посмотрите документацию внимательно, то поймете, что можно выводить в различных форматах.

Вот цитата с [документации](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

===========

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

===========

В этой цитате говориться, что если дата будет сохранена в виде текста, но в правильном формате, тогда встроенные функции будут работать нормально.  Но опять же, ничего не говориться о сортировке и условиях для выборки.

А то, что конкрентый SQLite Extert не отображает правильно дату... А он просто не знает, что нужно поле - дата и как ее правильно отобразить. Я предлагаю не переживать по этому поводу.